# How to access items from two lists in circular order?

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists,

```
list_a = ['color-1', 'color-2', 'color-3', 'color-4']
list_b = ['car1', 'car2', 'car3', 'car4' ........... 'car1000']
```

I need to access the elements in a circular order of `list_a`:

```
['color-1']['car1']
['color-2']['car2']
['color-3']['car3']
['color-4']['car4']
['color-1']['car5']  #list_a is starting from color-1 once it reaches end
['color-2']['car6']  #... goes on until end of items in list_b
```

I tried this, it doesn't work. Please advise.

```
start=0
i=0
for car_idx in xrange(start, end):
    if i <= len(color_names):
        try:
            self.design(color_names[i], self.cars[car_idx])
            i+=1
        except SomeException as exe:
            print 'caught an error'
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to make a cyclic iterable out of `list_a`.
Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair items from the cyclic iterable with items from `list_b`. The iterable returned by `zip` will stop when the shortest of the iterables passed to `zip` (i.e. `list_b`) ends.

```
import itertools as IT
list_a = ['color-1', 'color-2', 'color-3', 'color-4']
list_b = ['car1', 'car2', 'car3', 'car4', 'car5', 'car6', 'car1000']

for a, b in zip(IT.cycle(list_a), list_b):
    print(a, b)
```

prints

```
color-1 car1
color-2 car2
color-3 car3
color-4 car4
color-1 car5
color-2 car6
color-3 car1000
```

Comment: You beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

Use the modulo operator `%` to index into the proper range:

```
len_a = len(list_a)
len_b = len(list_b)
end = max(len_a, len_b)
for i in range(end):
    print(list_a[i % len_a], list_b[i % len_b])
    # ... do something else
```

Comment: this is nice because of how it is agnostic as to which list is the shortest.